# AWS Lambda and Log4j2 Logging on CloudWatch

Tags: aws-lambda, log4j2

I have an AWS Lambda Function, when executed gives errors related to reading Log4j2 file on cloudWatch.
I have log4j2 configuration related to AWS Lambda Logging. Added configuration to Plugin to remove default loading for Log4j2

Could you please help me resolve the below error

```
2019-10-01 14:39:54,029 main ERROR Error processing element Lambda: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2019-10-01 14:39:54,031 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Lambda
2019-10-01 14:39:54,054 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for Lambda
2019-10-01 14:39:54,056 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin for element Appenders: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
.
.
.
.
2019-10-01 14:39:55,839 main ERROR AppenderRef contains an invalid element or attribute "_ref"
2019-10-01 14:39:55,840 main ERROR Appender references must contain a reference
2019-10-01 14:39:55,893 main ERROR Null object returned for AppenderRef in Root.
2019-10-01 14:39:55,894 main ERROR Root contains an invalid element or attribute "_level"
2019-10-01 14:39:59,837 main ERROR Error processing element Lambda: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
```

Here is my Log4j2.YAML Configuration

```
Configuration:
 Appenders:
  Lambda:
   PatternLayout:
    pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"
   _name: Lambda
 Loggers:
  Root:
   AppenderRef:
    _ref: Lambda
   _level: info
 _packages: "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2"
```

Here is my Maven POM for Logging Dependencies

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/Log4j2Plugins.dat</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```